# Cannot get recurring calendar events with sdk lower than 14

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I am trying to get today's calendar events and successfully do if it's not a recurring event. But i cannot get the event if it's recurring. Is there any way to solve this problem ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the Calendar API has been released **ONLY AND EXCLUSIVELY** for Android 4.0+ (API Level 14+).

Comment: Yeah but it's possible to get calendar events without Calendar API so maybe there is a way to get recurring events

Comment: And will it work for which API Levels? 7? 8 to 13? and then? If you find a method, let me know, I' interested too (I'm going to support API 8 to 18).